# How do I install Google Tag Manager on Wordpress subdomain for the same Google Analytics that is on my main domain?

Tags: google-analytics, domains, subdomain, google-tag-manager

Basically I have a Heroku app on a main domain and a wordpress blog on a subdomain as blog.maindomain.com. I have google tag manager installed on the herokuapp that tracks the main domain.

How am I able to also allow my wordpress to have the same functionality? I want to be able to view all the analytics in a single account.

EDIT: I don't have to use GTM on the wordpress website, just as long as the data is showing on the same GA account.

Comment: In WordPress, functionality is added through extensions.   There are tons of [extensions that can add Google Tag Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/google-tag-manager) and [extensions that can add Google Analytics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/google-analytics) to WordPress

Answer (score 1):

From your question it isn't very clear if you have GTM deployed on wordpress already or not. If not, get it on there via a plugin or by editing the template code to add the GTM code.

### GTM Version

As far as getting sudomain.domain.com traffic to appear in the same analytics view, you need to use the same UA code in `Tracking ID` field of the the `pageview` tag in GTM and modify one thing. Specifically under `More Settings` --> `Fields to Set` add an entry with `cookieDomain` as the Field Name and `auto` as the Value. This will cause google to push pageviews to the same Google Analytics Account and event connect the same session since the `cookieDomain` `auto` part will cause GTM to set the analytics cookie to the highest domain it can which on `sudomain.domain.com` will resolve to `domain.com`

### Hardcoded

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The cookieDomain part is in this line `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');` with the UA code being the same you use on the domain.com site.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few different plugins available that help you install Google Tag Manager on your Wordpress website.  You can check out just a few of them here:

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=tag+manager